# find() and findOne() not working in browser console w/ MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

In my browser console `Posts` works, but I get errors with legitimate `_id` values with `find()` or `findOne()`:

`Posts.findOne({_id: 5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva})`

```
VM10024:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: Got it working with `FindOne()`, was missing the quotes: `Posts.findOne({_id: "5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva"})`. However `find()` shows the entire collection, thought it should show only the specific _id `.find({_id: "5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva"})`

Comment: Can you try `.find({_id: "5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva"}).fetch()`

Comment: You can directly put in the id without the wrapper object for find as well: `.find("5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva").fetch()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't recreate that exact error, but I noticed you don't have quotes around the _id you are searching for.

So instead of this:

```
Posts.findOne({_id: 5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva})
```

try:

```
Posts.findOne({_id: '5FSZhpYDcq4XWkTva'})
```